# Shared information between deferred tasks

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached, deferred

I am trying to design a basic web crawler in Google App Engine that will grab documents from websites.  The problem I have is that I need to share between the task queue the pages it already has visited.  I attempted to do this with Memcache but it doesn't appear to be working.  What is the best approach?

```
    memcache_results = memcache.get(root_url, namespace='charlotte')
    if memcache_results:
        if url in memcache_results:
            return False
        else:
            pass
    else:
        memcache_results = []
    memcache.add(root_url, memcache_results.append(url), 60 * 60, namespace='charlotte')

    print memcache_results

    charlotte = SpiderWorker(root_url)
    charlotte.get_page(url)
    links = charlotte.grab_links()

    for url in links:
            deferred.defer(spin_worker, root_url=root_url, url=url, _queue='doc-repo')
```

Comment: `memcache_results.append(url)` doesn't return a value so your call to `memcache.add` is storing nothing. Try fixing that first.

Comment: @JoshJ Fixed, although it seems to only save one, and then adds the url it is fetching.